# Performance: Declaration in loop VS Reinitialisation in loop

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop

I have been wondering and couldn't find a clear answer on this subject.

Imagine the following two examples.

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<maxLimit;i++)
{
    //code here
}
```

2nd example

```
for(int i=0;i<maxLimit;i++)
{
    //code here
}
```

Basically if they are like that I believe both would behaviour exactly the same but my questioning comes into place when considering this

```
while(!file.EOF)
{
    for(int i=0;i<maxLimit;i++)
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

When the 2nd example is inside a loop itself how does it perform? Is it more efficient to declare it beforehand and simply put it back to 0 or is the execution time the same as declaring it inside?

Personnally I usually put it like number 2 because I find it better visually speaking. But I,m wondering if it's inside a loop what the effect of it would be.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Have you considered... testing it?

Comment: Where you declare such a variable is really unlikely to give any meaningful performance difference.

Comment: The most important thing here, rather than asking what's more efficient, or even more readable, is what the scope of the variable is. If you have a variable than can be used outside of its scope, you introduce the possibility for bugs and abuse of the variable.

Comment: was the idea not to have the second for loop like `for(int i=0; i < maxLimit; ++i) {.. } ` (hence the `int`)?

Comment: Thank you all for your great answers! We learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most modern compilers are sufficiently sophisticated that any decision you make at this level is likely to make no difference whatsoever (to clarify, after analysis the compiler may have transformed both into the same internal representation - being the most efficient implementation). But if you're not convinced, the golden rule in this kind of case is to check with a profiler.

Answer (score 2):

It *shouldn't* matter whether you declare it before a `for`-loop because that's what happens even if you declare the variable inside it. Whatever expression lies before the first **;** is executed *before* the loop body, so the resulting assembly code should be completely identical.

In practice it doesn't matter if you declare the variable right before the `for`-loop, hundreds of lines before the loop or inside the for-loop body. The program behavior remains *exactly* the same, and as such compiler can, and usually will know how to optimize trivial cases like these.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are major performance issues with either case. I usually prefer to use example 2 as well, mainly because I know the exact scope of the variable and I don't end up getting myself in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

For a `int` value, this will have exactly zero impact.  If the variable had a non-trivial constructor, it might make a difference.  As everyone else stated, write the code first, profile the code, and then consider optimizing.  This change is almost always a micro-optimization at best.